# How to refine Synthetic Events in Flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, generics, ecmascript-6, flowtype

So I have a handler that accepts different kinds of `SyntheticEvent`s with this code:

```
    defaultProps = {
            events: [
                'mousemove',
                'keydown',
                'wheel',
                'DOMMouseScroll',
                'mouseWheel',
                'mousedown',
                'touchstart',
                'touchmove',
                'MSPointerDown',
                'MSPointerMove',
            ],
            element:
              (typeof window === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : typeof window) ===
            'object'
                ? document
                : {},
    }

    componentDidMount() {
            this.props.events.forEach((eventName: string) => {
                if (this.props.element) {
                    this.props.element.addEventListener(
                        eventName,
                        this.handleEvent(),
                    );
                }
            });
    }    
    handleEvent = (event: SyntheticEvent<*>): void => {
          if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
            // This event is a MouseEvent.
          } else if (event instanceof KeyboardEvent) {
          } else {
          }
        }
```

However, the above code throws an error which says `MouseEvent (this type is incompatible with SyntheticEvent)` same for `KeyboardEvent`. At first I thought `SyntheticEvent` is a catch all type for all events.

Comment: *"At first I thought `SyntheticEvent` is a catch all type for all events."* No, it's the unified event object created by React. It's not a native browser event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my main problem is differentiating `SyntheticEvent` and `Event` class. I initially thought all `Event` are converted to `SyntheticEvent`s in React.

When adding an event listener like `element.addEventListener` the callback emits an `Event` object and not a `SyntheticEvent`. I was using `addEventListener` and not the `onClick` prop for the component.